# Free software to maintain server list/process list

Tags: gratis, linux, web-apps, self-hosted, inventory

We have around 150 servers in our project. Right now we are managing these servers' details in Excel sheets (Prod, Non-prod, IPs and services running in them).

I am searching for a software where we can save all these details once and access using a web UI.

We don't need many features in this. No need of automatic scanning of servers. We just need to see these details as saved by us. 
Hostname IP Environment 'server class as defined by us".

Could someone suggest a freeware installable in RedHat 6?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a view of all of your servers, with status & running processes, I would take a look at [GRR](https://github.com/google/grr).

- Provide a list of all entrolled servers
- Show what processes are running on them
- Show status
- Post Mortum Anaysis
- Roll out upgrades
- Free, gratis & open source.

Note that you can apply lables to each server to simplify identification, role, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [RackTables](http://racktables.org/), might be what you're looking for.

It's made for datacenters, but you can probably adapt it to your needs.

Their own description:

> Racktables is a nifty and robust solution for datacenter and server
>   room asset management. It helps document hardware assets, network
>   addresses, space in racks, networks configuration and much much more!

Answer (score 0):

[Remmina](http://www.remmina.org/) might meet your needs. It is a remote access client that lets you enter a list of servers by name, group them together, and log into them via SSH, VNC, or RDP.

However, it is a GTK+ graphical desktop application, not web-based.

Comment: How does this allow monitoring services and other info? This is just an RDP client with grouping!